# Image loading extremely slow from Cloud firestore using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve image data from cloud firestore, but when I do so the image takes an extremely long time to load, sometimes not appearing at all.

Here is how I retrieve the image:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    Future<String> getProfilePic() async {
      final CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('UserNames');

      final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;

      final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

      return result.data()['profilepic'];
    }
```

And to display it:

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: getProfilePic(),
                  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Palette.lightGreen,
                      ));
                    }
                    return ClipOval(
                      child: Image.network(snapshot.data,
                          height: 100, width: 100, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: @GrahamD It changes with the recent one being 965 KB, but the one before that being 2.44 MB.  I'm only using the default apple images they give you in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache your image.

get this package:

```
cached_network_image 2.3.3
```

and change this code:

```
ClipOval(
                  child: Image.network(snapshot.data,
                      height: 100, width: 100, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                );
              },
            ),
```

To this code

```
ClipOval(
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              imageUrl:
              snapshot.data,
              placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below package in your `pubspec.yaml`.

```
cached_network_image: ^2.3.3
```

Try this code where you show the image :

```
             Material(
                child: snapshot.data != null
                    ? CachedNetworkImage(
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 1.0,
                            valueColor:
                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor),
                          ),
                          width: 50.0,
                          height: 50.0,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        ),
                        imageUrl: snapshot.data,
                        width: 50.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : Icon(
                        Icons.account_circle,
                        size: 50.0,
                        color: greyColor,
                      ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              )
```

Comment: I think its improved a bit but still it loads first and then only show the image. Is there any new solution for this?